# Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am getting an error when I am trying to open a presigned url for an encrypted file.
Here's my line to create the URL:

```
client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': 'bucket1', 'Key': a})
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>F6VK4TD1S0G4K6YR</RequestId>
<HostId>HOTh/YUsnxC4sSBYVsK5psX5vBz21q1M/qx+pVmKa6s7Np4EbRUbBV4toRJ52OAtqpHIejY03Zk=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Note, I am using the defaults in boto3 so it should be using signature 4 out of the box.
My bucket is encrypted using default encryption and I am using S3 bucket keys, and KMS key auto-generated by AWS.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The error is generated from where? `generate_presigned_url` generates the error?

Comment: @Marcin When I open the generated URL it gives me this error.

Comment: I also notice that the presigned URL returned to me by the lambda (my own one, which generates the URL) contains less headers than if you choose to generate it form the AWS console. I'd guess that's fine, but not sure. However, the presigned URL generated in the console seems to work just fine, but the one returned by lambda (which has less headers, just 4) returns the above error.

Comment: @Marcin The answer to your question is mentioned in the first sentence to my question: "I am getting an error when I am trying to open a presigned url for an encrypted file."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it, it was because of the signature version in boto3. Apparently boto doesn't set signature version 4 by default (I think I read in the docs somewhere it should).
Here are the changes I had to make:

```
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(signature_version='s3v4')
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=config)
response = s3.get_object(
    Bucket=os.getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
    Key=f'path/abc.json'
)
```